# Duplicate div every 15 seconds and add an animation to it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a marquee and I want to repeat it, but the first time that i run the animation it runs only one time, becouse i want it to start in the middle, then i want to duplicate that wrapper, with all the content and then apply a new animation to it, i want to clone it every 15 seconds, to make it repeat as a marquee

```js
setTimeout( function(){ 
  $('.wrapper').clone().addClass('wrapper2').insertAfter('.marquee');
        
        $('.wrapper2').css('-webkit-animation','second 30s infinite linear');
        $('.wrapper2').css('-moz-animation','second 30s infinite linear');
        $('.wrapper2').css('-o-animation','second 30s infinite linear');
        $('.wrapper2').css('animation','second 30s infinite linear');
        
    }  , 15000 );
```

```css
    @-webkit-keyframes scroll{
        0%{-webkit-transform: translate(-24%,0);}
        100%{-webkit-transform: translate(-100%,0);}
    }

    // Second animation to add to the clone wrapper every 15 seconds
    @-webkit-keyframes second{
       0%{-webkit-transform: translate(0,0);}
       100%{-webkit-transform: translate(-100%,0);}
    }

    .wrapper{
       display: inline-block;
       padding-left: 100%;
       -webkit-animation:scroll 25s 1 linear;
       -moz-animation:scroll 25s 1 linear;
       -o-animation:scroll 25s 1 linear;
       animation:scroll 25s 1 linear;
       background-color: brown;
       height: 50px;
       width: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="marquee">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- <div class="date"></div>-->
            <div class="pueblatemp"></div>
            <div class="warlotemp"></div>
            <div class="difference"></div>
            <div class="time"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have add it to my question

Comment: Could you post html, css, and js in a snippet? That would be a big help

Comment: Thanks for adding it to the question. Do you have the markup as well? I have no idea where `.marquee` is for example. Preferably jsfiddle it or make a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the animation to run infinitely then you dont need jQuery to achieve this. You can use pure CSS like the code below using **animation-iteration-count**.

> Please note that there will a blank area in the container as a result
>   of the marquee moving. This can be solved using jQuery.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-24%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
// Second animation to add to the clone wrapper every 15 seconds
@-webkit-keyframes second {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: scroll 25s 1 linear;
  -moz-animation: scroll 25s 1 linear;
  -o-animation: scroll 25s 1 linear;
  animation: scroll 25s 1 linear;
  background-color: brown;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Infinite loop (you can also set any number of iteriations that you want*/
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- <div class="date"></div>-->
    <div class="pueblatemp"></div>
    <div class="warlotemp"></div>
    <div class="difference"></div>
    <div class="time"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, you don't need to use vendor prefixes (-webkit, -moz and -o) if you don't need to support < IE10 as all major browsers are supporting the [**animation**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) property.

Answer (score -1):

I think this could solve it for you ;)

I reduced the interval so it's easier to visualize.

```js
setInterval( function(){ 
  $('.marquee').append($('.wrapper').first().clone().addClass('wrapper2').removeClass('wrapper1'));
  
}, 1000 );
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes scroll{
        0%{-webkit-transform: translate(-24%,0);}
        100%{-webkit-transform: translate(-100%,0);}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes second{
       0%{-webkit-transform: translate(-24%,0);}
       100%{-webkit-transform: translate(-100%,0);}
    }

    .wrapper{
       display: inline-block;
       padding-left: 100%;
       background-color: brown;
       height: 50px;
       width: 50px;
    }
    .wrapper1{
      -webkit-animation:scroll 25s 1 linear;
      -moz-animation:scroll 25s 1 linear;
      -o-animation:scroll 25s 1 linear;
      animation:scroll 25s 1 linear;
     }
    .wrapper2{
      -webkit-animation: second 30s infinite linear;
      -moz-animation: second 30s infinite linear;
      -o-animation: second 30s infinite linear;
      animation: second 30s infinite linear;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="marquee">
        <div class="wrapper wrapper1">
            <!-- <div class="date"></div>-->
            <div class="pueblatemp"></div>
            <div class="warlotemp"></div>
            <div class="difference"></div>
            <div class="time"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You just must be careful when cloning elements, make sure to clone only one of them.

See this:

```js
setInterval( function(){ 
  $('.hey').append($('.rotating').clone());
  
}, 1000 );
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
    from{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.rotating {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hey">
  <div class='rotating'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working fine, but did you know why it is not displaying in the same line as the original marquee

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "same line".